# Which tense is more acceptable for using in the following case?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple, present-perfect-progressive

My girlfriend is going to come to me and to ask me: "Jon, how was it today? What did you do today?"

I want to tell her that all the day I studied and made homework. So which tense is more acceptable for using in this case?

> 1) I have been learning / studying whole the day and made homework
>   (Present Perfect Continuous)
>
> 2) I learned / studied whole the day and made homework (past simple)
>
> 3) I I have learnt / studied whole the day and made homework (present
>   perfect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before choosing 1 to 3, let me correct some background errors first.

"My girlfriend are going to come to me and to ask me" should be 
"My girlfriend is coming to see me and will ask me" (more natural, although you are grammatically correct.)

"...What did you today?" should be 
"...What did you do today?"

"whole the day" should be 
"the whole day"

(1) is fine, but "made" should be "making" too.
(2) is also fine, but "study" is preferred.

Whether to choose (1) or (2) depends on if you think the "day" has ended, or if the whole studying has passed. If you were still studying when she asked you, it should be (1).

(2) and (3) are close. In both cases you think the "day" has ended, but in (3) it seems to tell people the "day" has just ended, while in (2) the "day" has ended for a very long time, perhaps 6 hours, 6 months or 6 years?